# Render an iFrame dynamically in Firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe

I generate an iFrame dynamically like this

```
var iframe=document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var iframedoc=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframedoc.body.innerHTML="HI";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pbj7S/

It works in Google Chrome, Opera, Safari, but not in Firefox.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works :

```
var iframe=document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
setTimeout(function(){
    var iframedoc=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframedoc.body.innerHTML="HI";
}, 10);
```

The problem was that you were trying to access the iframe document before it was available in the DOM.

The delay isn't important, the important point is that browsers update the display (and some js accessible objects in the case of Firefox) only after the js thread has finished working.

Comment: Is there a surer way (`onload` maybe?). Because with a VERY slow computer, it won't work.

Comment: I think it's OK : the important point isn't really the delay but the fact that the javascript thread stops and thus the browser is allowed to manage the DOM modification consequences. I tested it with a delay of 1 (millisecond).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like that is necessary. You do not need to use timeout or anything for firefox to behave like chrome. In your code just set the source to 'javascript:' would do it. Example bellow:

```
iframe.src = 'javascript:';
```

or just use:

```
iframe.src = 'about:';
```

don't set with blank. Will work just fine in firefox, chrome, opera, etc....